# Flask application error, cannot find the directory of the file. [Errno 2] No such file or directory?

Tags: python, flask

I tried to run the application by typing **python3 runserver.py** in the command line.

but I keep getting the following error when I try to run my flask application.

**/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/*MacOS*/Python: can't open file 'runserver': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

I am using the file structure described here -> 
[Larger Applications - Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/packages/)

This is how my project is structured:

```
- myproject
    - myproject
        - __init__.py
        - myproject.py (views are here)
        - schema.sql
        - static
            - beautify.css
        - templates
           - stuff1.html
           - stuff1.html
           - stuff3.html
    - runserver.py
```

When I'm running the script python can't find runserver.py even though I'm running it in the directory where runserver is located in.

I am running it from **myproject/**.

One issue might be something with how the package is structured, another might be that python is looking in the wrong place for the runserver.py as the error shows /library/frameworks/python/framework... /Python, which isn't where runserver.py is located in. But why is it looking in that directory?

Any insight is appreciated,

Thanks

```
runserver.py 

from myblog import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

---

```
    __init__.py

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import myblog.myblog
```

Comment: Are you sure you're typing `python runserver.py` and not `python runserver`?

Comment: Yes, just did so again to confirm.

Comment: And you're sure that you're not in your *inner* `myproject` folder? And if you type `ls runserver.py` in the terminal you see the file

Comment: python3 runserver.py
myproject
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'runserver.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Can you show us the actual contents of `runserver.py`?

Comment: What is `myblog`? Is that something you installed with Pip?

Answer (score 0):

just run the below command in the terminal

"pip install --upgrade setuptools"

and rerun your python file